# How to get single value from array after using print_r

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an array `$_FILES` it can store multiple images.

When I use `print_r($_FILES)` after storing two images in this array it gives me following output:

```
Array ( [IMG_20170304_224950_jpg] => Array ( [name] => IMG_20170304_224950.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php4584.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 4098228 ) [IMG_20170305_075610_jpg] => Array ( [name] => IMG_20170305_075610.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php4602.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 5314040 ) )
```

In this I want to `echo` both of two images.

---

This is how my code looks like:

**index.php**

```
     <input id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar[]" multiple />
     <button id="upload" value="Upload" type="button">upload</button> 
    <div class="preview">
    </div>

   <div class="return_php"></div>

  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" ></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var form_data = new FormData(); 
    var number = 0;

    /* WHEN YOU UPLOAD ONE OR MULTIPLE FILES */
    $(document).on('change','#avatar',function(){
        console.log($("#avatar").prop("files").length);
        len_files = $("#avatar").prop("files").length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len_files; i++) {
            var file_data = $("#avatar").prop("files")[i];
            form_data.append(file_data.name, file_data);
            number++;
            var construc = '<img width="200px" height="200px" src="' +  window.URL.createObjectURL(file_data) + '" alt="'  +  file_data.name  + '" />';
            $('.preview').append(construc); 
        }
    }); 

    /* WHEN YOU CLICK ON THE IMG IN ORDER TO DELETE IT */
    $(document).on('click','img',function(){

        var filename = $(this).attr('alt');
        var newfilename = filename.replace(/\./gi, "_");
        form_data.delete($(this).attr('alt'))
        $(this).remove()

    });

    /* UPLOAD CLICK */
    $(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
        $.ajax({
                    url: "target.php",
                    dataType: 'script',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,                         // Setting the data attribute of ajax with form_data
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.return_php').html(data);
                    }
           })
    })
});
```

**target.php**

```
<?php


 var_dump($_FILES);
 print_r ($_FILES);

foreach ($array as $key => $image) {
  /* Now you can get each image name */
 echo $image['name'];
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: but what are you want to print? the image name? a <img tag with images files?

Comment: i want to print image name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to print the image name:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $image) {
  /* Now you can get each image name */
  echo $image['name'];
}
```

EDIT: This is a upload file example

**index.html**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select image to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile'])) {
  print "Your file information:";
  var_dump($_FILES['uploadFile']);
} else {
  print "You need to upload a file.";
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help you if i can.

Comment: what if i want to upload the image?

Comment: You need to do a HTML form with a <input type="file" name="..." /> and get de upload image in your php with the $_FILES array. Try to search "upload file with php" in google, it's easy.

Comment: are you here sir? if have seen this comment plz see my code below and tell me how can i upload file cause i am not able to use input name.  i don't understand ajax so much ,should i use form_data instead of avatar

Comment: You don't need to use Ajax, try to add a `<input type="file" name="uploadFile" />` in your form and then, in your php code you can access to file with `$_FILES['uploadFile']`, put a `var_dump($_FILES);` to see the variables.

Comment: but the real data is in 'form_data.' 'uploadFile' will upload the old input but the new input is in 'form_data ' it means there is no use of form_data here .please see the code below

Comment: Added a form example to upload a file in mi answer, now you have to adapt it to your code. Edit: I can't see that code you're referring to :S

Comment: if you can see below code of index.php and upload.php file .i have append data in form_data  it store data after deleting selected image , now i want to upload the files in file_data which is a new input

Comment: The problem in your code is that the input are out of the form, see my example, you need a <form> before the <input> field. You may need to read the <form> documentation to understand how it works. And please, edit your main question or create other post better than answer your question with other question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
foreach($array as $val)
{ 
    echo $val['name'];
}
```

Comment: This may be an answer the question. But I agree that the question itself is not clear and lacks basic php knowledge. Please explain in details why your solution might work for @nitin-verma and also try to explain what print_r does and what $_FILES is. All this information could help him understand what went wrong.